# ProgressDialiog crashing the app if I use AsyncTask?

Tags: android, mobile, android-asynctask, onclick

I've got a button, and on the onClick method I've got an event(request).I'm using the AsyncTasc to display a proggressDialog while the request is processed. The problem is when I tap the button, I get the progressDialog and after a few seconds the app crashes.
Here is my code:

```
 joinButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                        @Override
                        protected void onPreExecute() {
                            super.onPreExecute();
                            nextConf = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                            nextConf.setMessage("message");
                            nextConf.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                            nextConf.setCancelable(false);
                            nextConf.show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            EventBus.getBus().post(new MainActivity.ConferenceSwitchRequestEvent());
                            return null;
                        }

                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                            nextConf.dismiss();
                        };

                    }.execute();
                }
            });
        }

        return view;
```

and these are the crash log:

```
01/com.xxx.xxx E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c8ad68 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1061,288} that was originally added here
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:462)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
        at com.xxx.xxxx.ConferenceMembersListAdapter$1$1.onPreExecute(ConferenceMembersListAdapter.java:141)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
        at com.xxx.xxx.ConferenceMembersListAdapter$1.onClick(ConferenceMembersListAdapter.java:133)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas why?Thank you in advance.

Comment: can u plz post  EventBus.getBus() code

Comment: Comment nextConf.show(); and run again then you can find the real issue. Issue may be with this  EventBus.getBus().post(new MainActivity.ConferenceSwitchRequestEvent());

Comment: Hi Mona! sure, this is my EventBus.get() code :public final class EventBus {
 private static Bus sBus = new Bus();

 public static Bus getBus() {
  return sBus;
 }
}

Comment: Hi Sreejith SP! Commented out //nextConf.show() and it still crashes. I think the problem is on       @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                EventBus.getBus().post(new MainActivity.ConferenceSwitchRequestEvent());

                                return null ;
                            } shouldn't return null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crashes because on ` protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {
                               EventBus.getBus().post(new MainActivity.ConferenceSwitchRequestEvent());
                               Void progress;
                               return null;

returns `null`